# Where is the build location specified in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build-automation

When building my project, it says:

"Build file 'C:\Users*******\Desktop*****************\uild' does not exist."

There is not a uild file. I've looked in the build.gradle, the settings.gradle and the gradlew as well as the gradle folders but I cant seem to see where the build location is specified.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Show us how you run build of you project, please. What directory, what command, where is directory of project (where build.gradle located).

Comment: Im running the build task from the Gradle gui, [here](http://i.imgur.com/sWXhAxb.png) are the files, in which you will see my gradle files. can't go into too much depth.

Comment: What if you start build from command line, from directory where build.gradle located?

Comment: I have just tried with the same results :(

Comment: I suppose in this case best what you can do - add to you question content of build.gradle and add as much details as you can (Including full output of build process).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like there could be a "b" missing. Are you maybe using a single slash as a path separator somewhere, e.g. in settings.gradle?

Comment: I have looked in settings.gradle, build.gradle and gradlew.bat and gradlew. In all of those there is only one reference of build and its in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem.

I was doing gradlew -build instead of gradlew build. There should be no dash before the build.

Comment: Your comment is well timed, I am starting to work on Gradle again! I don't think this was my issue. I was using the gradle GUI at the time, and it is set as a default task for the project.